# changing font size in geom_col aes fill group names

Tags: r, size, font-size, fill, geom-col

I am creating a bar plot using aes(fill=dummy variable) so I have 4 bars: I am basically showing proportions for a 2x2 model - How do I change the font size of the names for the different groups?

```
ggplot(summary2, aes(story, prop_agreement)) + #story is either "Freedom" or "Cyber" 
geom_col(aes(fill = Mindset), position = "dodge", alpha = .7) + #mindset is either "Doubt" or "Control"
scale_fill_manual(values = wes_palette(name="Moonrise2", n = 2)) +
labs(title = "Proportion of agreement in Control vs Doubt, by Story", 
              x = "Story", 
              y = "Proportion of agreement") +
theme_minimal()
```

QUESTION: How do I change font size for how cyber/freedom, doubt/control appear in the plot?

Comment: It will help to provide the data `summary2`, and/or the output plot, so we can see *where* these words appear. Do you mean in the legend, or the axis labels, for example?

Answer (score 0):

this is the plot I am working with >> I want to change the font size of the legends for mindset: control/doubt and for story: cyber privacy / freedom of speech

[this is the plot I am working with >> I want to change the font size of the legends for mindset: control/doubt and for story: cyber privacy / freedom of speech](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7t8u.png)